# QuickBooks IPP Rest API 3.0 CustomerRef in Invoice

Tags: api, rest, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

When I use the IPP Rest API 3.0 to create a invoice, a example like this:

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
       <Line>
            <Description>Installation labor</Description>
            <Amount>420.00</Amount>
            <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
            <SalesItemLineDetail>
                <ItemRef>33</ItemRef>
            </SalesItemLineDetail>
        </Line>
      <CustomerRef>20</CustomerRef>
</Invoice>
```

In this example, 20 is the Id of this customer.

Now, for a third party program, it might not know the Id of this customer, might know the Name of the customer,  so , I understand I can always query the customer to get the Id back first, then use that Id in this invoice creating format.

But my question is,  can I just use the name without specify the Id of this customer to create this invoice?

Will the following works?

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
       <Line>
            <Description>Installation labor</Description>
            <Amount>420.00</Amount>
            <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
            <SalesItemLineDetail>
                <ItemRef>33</ItemRef>
            </SalesItemLineDetail>
        </Line>
      <CustomerRef name="ACB Company"></CustomerRef>
</Invoice>
```

Further more,  If it DOES work, does this logic apply to all the ReferenceType in the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In API payload, you can't refer objects by name ( this behavior was partially supported in old V2 API which is now deprecated ).

You can verify this behavior using Apiexplorer.

- https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

In this case, you should query the customer by name and then extract the ID to refer it in the invoice create payload.

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason for not supporting this anymore? Without this, creating one invoice will end up a lot of more http requests just to resolve the references , not good for the performance on both sides.

Comment: It is a design choice. I believe, in server side, looking referenced object by name is not a better choice compared to looking object by id. Another thing is, in name entities(customer,vendor and employee), there is an unique name constraint. But for other transaction entities that is not applicable.